# (UE4) Why won't this Custom Event execute?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I want when the player presses the left key, the door/gate opens. There are doors constantly spawning in the level, but you can only open the one LEAST recently spawned, so I have the doors in an array. So when you press left, it gets the door at index 0 and opens only THAT door. Idk if that makes sense...

Here you can see what I'm doing:
[The Error in my Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDZpy.png)

I've been trying to figure out what this stupid error is literally all day. Why can't I figure something out that looks so simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image, you should wire `Pressed` to the `Cast to` node, and wire cast successful to the `Open` node...

Also make sure your `PlayerBP_Normal` is able to receive player input so that input action can be triggered.

And to get `[0]` of the array to get the oldest door makes sense I think. Just to make sure you add spawned doors to the end of the array, so the first one is the oldest.

Comment: Thank you, that worked (bruh)! But one more thing (sorry). My array is stored in a different blueprint (GameMode). I set the array as public so that I could access it from the playerBP. But now there's an error saying I must have a reference to the blueprint that the array is in. I'm not sure how to get that. I'm thinking if I should just move these nodes to the blueprint (my GameMode) where the array is.

Comment: To access the GameMode object is very easy. https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/BlueprintAPI/Game/GetGameMode/index.html Check here. The node returns base class so you also need a cast, like your door BP. Where to put the code is based on your design, I'm not sure which one is the best solution :P

Comment: Lol, I ended up figuring out how to reference an actor/BP. Turns out all I had to do was add a variable of type whatever bp I wanna reference. I'm pretty much a beginner user(started this month). But thanks brother :)

Comment: No problem, if you need any help just ask :P Glad to have more people using Unreal!

Comment: I have another question, but Stack won't let me ask >.< Apparently I've asked 3 questions RECENTLY, when I asked one 2 days ago, and before that my last question was a few months ago, so what the hell.. It's a weird error too.